# Creating 100 prime number randomly within 1000

Tags: java, primes

My coding is to crate 100 prime number randomly within 1000, there's one part in it has error message and I'm unclear about it, it is as follow:

```
int date, count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    date = new Integer(value.nextInt(1000));
    if(date > 1 && prime(date) != -1)
        tree.add(date);
}
```

The error message it sent to me is: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to int`

and `The method add(Object) in the type TreeSet is not applicable for the arguments (int)`.

However, I thought int represents integer? 
Plus, how does `date > 1 && prime(date) != -1` work? I cannot find any example online including format like prime().

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Looks like you should declare `Integer date` isntead of `int date`;  `int` is a primitive type, it's not an `Object` in Java

Comment: Why to do `date = new Integer(value.nextInt(1000));`. Simple `date = value.nextInt(1000);` will be enough.

Comment: And you should also make sure that you declare your tree as a TreeSet <Integer>

Comment: Just curious, but which version of Java are you using? Usually it would automatically convert between Integer and int is you are using version 1.5 or higher...

Comment: @Endling It's 8.0.50.13, I'm going to update it to 7 since it's out of date.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Oh I thought here we should put datatype before `date, count = 0` ?

Comment: @Vivi: At least `date` should be `Integer`; e.g. `Integer date; int count;`

Comment: @Vivi What does your prime function do? Does it return the number if it's a prime number, but return -1 if not?

Comment: @Vivi With this code, it's very likely that you generate less than 100 prime numbers, because you run the loop exactly 100 times. As soon as a random number is no prime number you are missing one. Instead, use a while loop that checks for the size of the set.

Comment: @primitivwurzel prime returns prime number, but I also don't get `prime(date) != 1`, that's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
int count = 0;
Integer date = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    date = new Integer(value.nextInt(1000));
    if(date > 1 && prime(date) != -1)
        tree.add(date);
}
```

Comment: But why I cannot use `int date, count = 0` if i also change below datatype to int

Answer (score 0):

To generate a set of 100 different prime numbers use this code:

```
public Set<Integer> generatePrimes() {
    HashSet<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    while (result.size() < 100) {
        int candidate = random.nextInt(1000);
        if (!result.contains(candidate) && isPrime(candidate)) {
            result.add(candidate);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private boolean isPrime(int candidate) {
    // determine whether candidate is a prime number
}
```

Comment: Sorry since I refer to the book, so can you give suggestion based on my coding?